# Why Post has no field 'publish' as the app cache isn't ready yet so if this is an auto-created field, it won't be ready yet?

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner to Django. I am doing a blogsite project. I am creating a datebase for the blog. But when I run the command `python manage.py makemigrations blog`, I get this error.

**error :**

> FieldDoesNotExist(django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: Post has
> no field named 'publish'. The app cache isn't ready yet, so if this is
> an auto-created related field, it won't be available yet.)

**This is my blog.models.py file :**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    
    class Status(models.TextChoices):
        DRAFT = 'DF', 'Draft'
        PUBLISHED = 'PB', 'Published'
    
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
    body = models.TextField()
    published = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2,choices=Status.choices,default=Status.DRAFT)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-publish']
        indexes = [ models.Index(fields=['-publish']),]

    def __str__(self):
        return self. Title
```

I don't know the problem. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the non-existing field `publish` in your index and ordering definitions:

```py
class Meta:
    ordering = ['-publish']
#                 ^^^^^^^
    indexes = [ models.Index(fields=['-publish']),]
#                                      ^^^^^^^
```

You probably meant to reference the `published` field instead